# Drupal WYSIWYG Plugin API Documentation

Tags: drupal, documentation, wysiwyg

Anyone know where to go to find decent Drupal Project API documentation? Specifically, I'd like to look at the WYSIWYG Plugin API documentation but I can't find any place where that's actually documented even though it's referenced in the WYSIWYG Project quite a few times.

If there's some good site out there that has all the documentation on Drupal I could ever hope to get, I'd appreciate knowing about it because drupal.org is not being helpful at the moment. I tried getting a grip on Drupal through documentation and it is a **pain** to try and find anything without using a search engine but, even with a search engine, I can't find anything on WYSIWYG Plugin API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups for Drupal WYSIWYG : https://groups.drupal.org/wysiwyg

Good luck ^^

Comment: So, what you're saying is no. I suppose I can accept that.